# Retrieving values from a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Trying to port my sudoku solving algorithm (which now works!) to javascript, and trying to retrieve the initial values from a series of dropdowns on a page. The basic format of the dropdowns is as follows:

```
<form action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="sudoku00">
                    <option value=0></option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

The javascript I'm using to try to retrieve these to an array is as follows, but doesn't seem to work:

```
var grid=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]...]
for (var i=0; i<9; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<9; j++){
        var current=document.getElementById("sudokuCell"+i.string+j.string);
        grid[i][j]=current.options[current.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
```

It ends up setting the first cell to undefined and the rest to 0 when none of the dropdowns are changed from blank, and each entry in the smaller arrays becomes undefined when I change the dropdowns to anything other than blank.
Also if any of this is bad form please let me know, I'm still pretty new to javascript.

Edit: here's the whole thing. Sorry about the bad id, was typing from memory and missed that. http://jsfiddle.net/2Me7E/

Comment: I personally like suduko solvers just because it reminds me of an N-Queens problem.  :)

On another note, you seem to have issues with:  `string` needing to be `string()` and make sure all the select IDs are correct.  If you would like i could make you a fiddle

Comment: `i.string` isn't going to do anything unless you define a `string()` function on the variable. If you're thinking you need to convert the number in `i` to a string like in Java or C#, where you'd use `ToString()`, then you don't have to do that in JS. JS will automatically convert the number if you're concatenating it with a string.

Answer (score 1):

`i.string` should be `i.toString()` and your selector is looking for id `sudokuCellxx` when your select list's id is `sudokuxx`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer i just wrote up in about 4 minutes.

http://jsfiddle.net/69b5p/

```
//make the grid
var $t = $("<table />"),
    $r = $("<tr />"),
    $c = $("<td />"),
    $sel = $("<select />"),
    $opt = $("<option />"),
    result = $t.clone(),
    selection = $sel.clone();
for (var i = 0; i<9; i++){
    selection.append($opt.clone().val(i+1).text(i+1));
}
for (var i = 9; i; i--){
    var row = $r.clone();
    for (var j = 9; j;j--){
        row.append($c.clone().append(selection.clone()));
    }
    result.append(row);
}


$("body").append(result);
```

and then you can just add some css:

```
table, tr, td{border: solid 1px black;}
```

**Edit:**   Adjusted this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/X4fF3/) such that your ID's are assigned AND wraps it with a form.

**Edit 2:**   http://jsfiddle.net/X4fF3/1/  gives an array of all the numbers in order left to right.

With the second edit you can easily find everything which belongs where, by doing something like:

9*R + C%9  where R is the row number and C is the column.  (this is programming so it would actually be 0-8 for each of them. :)

example:

```
function get(R,C){ return array[9*R + C%9]; }
```